# DataTables Plugin not being called to display Json Data

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I am new to MVC and JQuery so I appreciate all the help I can get.

I am trying to view data retrieved from SQL database on MVC view using JQuery DataTables Plugin.
Here is my Controller Action:

```
public JsonResult Index()
    {
        var subjects = _db.Subjects.Select(x => new SubjectViewModel()
        {
            SubjectName = x.SubjectName
        }).ToList();

        return Json(subjects, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And Here is my View:

```
@model IEnumerable.....
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div>
    <table id="mytable" class="display">
        <thead> <tr>
                <th> Subject Name </th>
        </tr> </thead>
     <tbody> </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.noConflict();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "SubjectViewModel")',
            type: 'Get',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#mytable').DataTable({
                    'aaData': response,
                    'aoColumns': [
                        { 'mData': 'SubjectName ' }
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have put all my javascript references in the layout page but even if I put them on this view it does not make a difference.
The result that I get is the raw json data that looks like:

```
{"SubjectName":"Mathematics"},{"SubjectName":"Accounting"},{"SubjectName":"Science"}
```

Please help me understand what I am missing in order for the dataTable to display the Json Data.
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using ajax for this. Just pass the model to the view and build the `<tbody>` elements using a `foreach` loop

Comment: I have no problem using the foreach loop as you suggest. I am learning how to use this plugin because of its added features e.g. easy search, sort & pagination. I intend to use it for a models with large numbers of records in the database.

Comment: You don't seem to understand - pass you model to the view. Build the `<table>` using a `foreach` loop and then apply the `DataTables` plugin to the `<table>` (its crazy to have the browser request your view, then basically say - sorry I forgot to send you all the data - waste some more time and resources making another call back to the server to get it)

Answer (score 0):

You already passed data as model to razor view, as @Stephen Muecke said use loop like below:

```
@model IEnumerable.....
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div>
    <table id="mytable" class="display">
        <thead> <tr>
                <th> Subject Name </th>
        </tr> </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>item</td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```